# How to keep the Kendo grid default grouping from being removed

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I have a grid which has default grouping by one of the columns e.g "Important". I allow grouping by other columns, but I want to lock my default grouping. So no one can remove this grouping.

I didn't find any property to achieve this. I tried using the DataBound event change class and removed the remove button of this column in the group header but later the Kendo script reverted this back to its original state.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Model(m => m
            .Id(z => z.Id))
        .Read(r => r.Action("myAction", "myController"))
        .Group(g=>g.AddDescending(c=>c.Important))
        )
    .Columns(c =>
    {
       c.Bound(d => d.Important)
            .Title("This is important")
            .Groupable(false)
            .Visible(true)
            .Hidden(true);

        c.Bound(d => d.otherColumn)
            .Title("otherColumn")
            .Groupable(true);

             ....
     }
     .Groupable()
     .Events(e=>e
        .Change("onChange")   
        .DataBound("dataBound")
      )
)
```

Comment: The column "important" has visible and hidden, both true: you don't want that, do you? Would removing that specific column header be a solution for you? If so, that's easily achievable

Comment: I want that :) I want hide this column so if I use visible(false) then column isn't show but the header text is like the model name. I have set other name, the same as title and I have value of this field next to title. I can use .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate() property but I couldn't show value of this fild when I used that. So this combination allow me to achieve this.

Comment: _Would removing that specific column header be a solution for you? If so, that's easily achievable_ @chiapa It's doesn't work

Comment: In case you still need it, I sort of answered what you want in another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29666145/1860561).