# Disable/remove close icon on Kendo Grid's default group column

Tags: kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI Grid for one of my solutions. I have this one task/requirement where I should be able to give a default grouping for the grid, and the user should not be able to remove this grouping from the UI.

There is one way of achieving this as in this jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/xzLfgsba/4/

If you look at the following example, the grouping is true but the grouping can be changed by clicking on k-group-delete icon or by dragging the grouped column back into the grid.
http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/xzLfgsba

```
group: [{field: "ShipName"}],
groupable: false
```

But there is one one problem with this solution, you do not have the group header(because the groupable is set to false) and you cannot sort based on the group it self.

Is there a way to show group header and also disable further changes to grouping of the grid?

Thank you.

Comment: `you do not have the group header(because the groupable is set to false) and you cannot sort based on the group it self` were you referring to the first fiddle for this? If so, you can still sort by clicking on the regular grid column headers

Comment: @gitsitgo: Thanks for the response.  Yes, I can sort by clicking on the column header it self. I just want to see if I can enable grouping and also disable the close button in the grouped button so that the user is not able remove the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the close handle (X button) is simple, just hide it. I can hide it programmatically but using CSS is much more effective.

```css
span.k-icon.k-group-delete{
    display:none;
}
```

Next step is to get rid of the draggable property of the grouping indicator. To do this, we destroy the draggable container. We need to do this *after* dataBound because the grid properties are re-applied every time dataBound is called.

```js
dataBound:function(e){
    setTimeout(function(){
         //get the indicator header
         var groupIndicatorHeader = $('.k-group-indicator').parent();
         if(!groupIndicatorHeader) return;
         //check if it is draggable eneabled
         var kendoDraggableObj =  $(groupIndicatorHeader).data('kendoDraggable');
         if(kendoDraggableObj) kendoDraggableObj.destroy();
    },0);
}
```

`setTimeout` is necessary to make it run after all dataBound and natural kendo code has finished running. Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexyu/qfyn9jwh/)** for this solution.

You will probably notice that this solution is very hacky, and it is. But sometimes you just gotta roll with it to get the customization you need.

Comment: Also while writing this answer I discovered that there's a difference in the sorting of the grouping indicator and the column header. The column header is applied on the entire grid, while the grouping indicator sort only sorts the current page's OrderIDs. This is why you will notice that both the column header AND the grouping indicator can be sorted at the same time, and in seemingly conflicting directions.

Comment: Thanks for the help @gitsitgo.  And yes, the sorting is a little questionable or can be modified to specific needs (if using server side sorting).

Comment: Is there a solution for Kendo Angular grid. I too have same requirement but control is angular grid.