# Disable Drag Drop Feature Kendo Angular Grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a requirement where I need to show the Grid group Header i.e. kendo-grid-group-panel but disable dragging of columns and Dropping from grid (user should not be able to add or remove groups columns using drag and drop feature). I have some default groups which I will be setting while rendering the Grid.

Sample: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/grouping/

My requirement is similar to [Disable/remove close icon on Kendo Grid's default group column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656737/disable-remove-close-icon-on-kendo-grids-default-group-column). but the solution is specific to kendo jQuery grid. I tried few work around but it didnt work.

Let me know if this is possible. Any help will be higly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi All I raised this with Kendo team.

Set [groupable] input properties of all the columns as false.

Then some custom CSS can be added in order to hide the "X" button of the Group tiles and to prevent the default click behavior of the Group tiles:

```
 kendo-grid-group-panel div[kendodraggable] .k-button.k-button-icon.k-bare{
    display: none;
  }
  kendo-grid-group-panel div[kendodraggable]{
    pointer-events: none;
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwyvhe?file=app/app.component.ts